# Mantain a "position" in a line of users who signed up in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Rails and Devise and I would like to do the following:

When a User goes to the Landing page, tell him how many people he has "ahead" of him (that is people who has already signed up for the beta version).  This would be as easy as knowing how many people are already on the system, so that would be easy.

However, I want to be able to track which position a particular User has in the line of sign up, and that position can change.  How? Well, if a User (after signing up) share his sign up on Facebook (A Facebook share button will be provided) I want to make him go 2 spots up on line.

I am wondering what would be a good way to track this positions and how to store them, taking into account that they can change depending on whether they share on Facebook (or Twitter)..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User model will need a position integer attribute and methods to move higher or lower. Thankfully a great gem exists to provide that functionality. Take a look at https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list.

The steps you'll need to take are:

1. Add `gem 'acts_as_list'` to your Gemfile
2. Add the integer `position` attribute to the User model (via a migration if it already exists)
3. Add calls to `move_higher` (meaning make the position a lower number) within the actions that you'd call when they share via social media

Comment: Dan Reedy, thanks for your suggestion.  I have a problem though. When creating a new User, I get the following error: "undefined method `position' for #<User:0xa15d074>" - Any thoughts on why this can be happening?

Comment: If the User model already existed you will need to add position as an integer column using a migration.